# Linux – cannot remove owned file with 777 permissions

Tags: linux, filesystems, file-permissions, rm

I've couple of files that I cannot remove using `rf -Rf` command. I'm the owner of those file and the group assigned to those files is also a group my user is in. What's even weirder is that I can edit their content and I can change the permissions for them, but I can't move or delete them.

```
ls -al
total 12
dr-xr-xr-x 3 rayell pg1083760 4096 2010-10-10 10:00 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 rayell pg1083760 4096 2011-09-02 04:33 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 rayell pg1083760    0 2011-09-02 06:38 default.settings.php
drwxrwxrwx 2 rayell pg1083760 4096 2011-09-02 04:33 files
-rwxrwxrwx 1 rayell pg1083760    0 2011-09-02 06:38 settings.php


rm -Rf *
rm: cannot remove `default.settings.php': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove directory `files': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove `settings.php': Permission denied
```

Can anyone tell me what is happening?

Comment: In general, consider using rm -rf DIRECTORY_NAME and not "*".  It will save you from that one time when you will think yourself in directory /some/where/safe but are instead in /home

Comment: Actually I did try that, it was just those 3 files that I couldn't remove so I have simplified to procedure a bit for this post's purpose.

Comment: Don't forget the lsattr and chattr command...

Answer (score 79, accepted):

To remove one file you need write permission on *the directory that contains*¹ this file.

Here the permissions are `dr-xr-xr-x 3 rayell pg1083760 4096 2010-10-10 10:00 .` So nobody (other than `root`) can remove files inside this directory. The owner must use `chmod` first.

—

<sup>1. There are pretty good reasons for that. By ‘removing’ a file with `rm`, you are in fact trying to *unlink* it from the directory (hardlinked copies will not be deleted).</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Another possible question is attribute

```
lsattr file
```

This command will show you attribute of the file
and a file with 'i' attribute cannot be modified (and be deleted)

so check your file's attribute and remove 'i' attribute if the attribute is been set

```
chattr -i file
```

Comment: The question shows that it's the directory permissions that don't allow writing.  No need to look further.

Comment: Ok, but this was the answer I needed! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that the parent directory has `chmod 705` or something like that. You can `chmod` the parent directory by the following command:

```
chmod -R 777 directory_name
```

After this, you can remove that directory and the files it contains.

Comment: Please don't condone making directories writable by *everybody*.  That's not good advice.

Comment: +1 - Agree, do not follow this advice, it's amazing, how this is plastered all over the internet... The amount of insecurity, caused by people advocating this is incredible...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and `chmod` alone didn't do the trick. I first had to change the owner (user and group) of the files I wanted to remove.

```
sudo chown -hR root:admin dir_to_delete
```

Explanation:

- `sudo`: make sure you have the proper rights
- `chown`: Linux command to change owner of a file
- `-hR`: change owner of directory and all subdirectories. I found it [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chown).
- `root`: name of new user
- `admin`: name of new group

I had already changed the modifiers to 777; I don't know if that was necessary or not.

Comment: Permissions of files within directory are irrelevant, only write permission on directory itself matters. Probably before `chown` you had been neither owner of directory nor member of directory owning group.

Answer (score 0):

Just for knowledge sake:
I solved it using sudo editing the sudoers file:

```
Cmnd_Alias MOVE = /bin/mv, /bin/rm
user ALL=(postgres) NOPASSWD:MOVE
```

In the procedure the user does:`sudo -u postgres rm /tmp/test.file`